# Angular UI router - acess stateParams from other state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am beginner for Angular and I am sorry for my bad english. I find similar questions and answers but it doesn't help to my code... I want something like this

```
.state('members.detail', {
            parent: "members",
            url: "/:id",
            templateUrl: "templates/members.detail.html",
            controller: 'membersDetailsController'
        })

.state('members.detail.fees', {
                parent: 'members.detail',
                url: '/fees',
                views: {
                  'items': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs/tab2-fees.html',
                    controller: 'Fees'
                  }
                }
        })
```

And I also have something like this:

```
myapp.controller('membersDetailsController', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {alert($stateParams.id);}
```

And:

```
<a ui-sref=".fees" ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('members.detail.fees') }">Fees</a>
```

I need id from first state to use in second state/fees-controller

P.S. there is similar question about this but doesn't help me (or didn't understand quite good) [Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from)

Answer (score 4):

You can't access `$state` and `$stateParams` directly in the template, you need to bind it to the scope:

`myapp.controller('Fees', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {
    $scope.params = $stateParams;
    $scope.currentState = $state;
};`

```
<a ui-sref=".fees" ng-class="{ active: params.id === someId }">Fees</a>
```

Note that ui-router also supports the [ui-sref-active](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active) directive that you can use to highlight elements depending on the active state.

Also note that nested routes inherit state parameters from their parents.

Comment: my next problem is that part 'someId'. I have users, and every user has own id. So every time when I click on user, id is changing...so I have dependency of  url: "/:id"

Comment: next thing, I have an error ReferenceError: $state is not defined

Comment: @PakiM I forgot to inject the state, as for to id: where does this id come from? It isn't really stated.

Comment: I use mysql base, set up api, so I can read user's id in html like {{user.id}}...it give me real value what I need. First time when I use that id is in .state('members.detail') , his controller uses $stateParams.id... now that same id I need in another state Fees in his controller. Hope you can catch me.. 

I also do this .run so I can use for ng-class={active: $state.includes()}; 

myapp.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;             
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});

Comment: I solve a problem, I didn't put '$stateParams' before function, in controler: myapp.controller('Fees', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
        
console.log($stateParams.id);
        
 }]);
thanx for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can access it exactly as you wrote from all of the child controllers.
Something like this:

```
myapp.controller('Fees', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {alert($stateParams.id);}
```

But you have a mistake in your "ui-sref" attribute.
It should look like this:

```
<a ui-sref="members.detail.fees({ id:1 })" ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('members.detail.fees') }">Fees</a>
```

Hope this would help.