# ng-click not working in ionic framework which is declared in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

On `infowindow` click I want to navigate to other page..

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $compile) {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.117181, 79.070339);

var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);
var contentString = "<button ng-click='gotoBooking()'>Book</button>";
var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: compiled[0]
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
});

marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(21.16581, 79.070339);

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map,
});

marker2.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.open(map, marker2);
});

$scope.map = map;
$scope.gotoBooking = function () {

    $state.go('app.makeBooking');
};
```

});

Comment: pls post the html code where ng-click is located

Comment: please update your html also where you use controler and click event

Comment: His click event is actually inside of the listener. `<button ng-click='Booking1()'>Make Booking</button>`

Comment: Please refer the link you could get some idea http://techfunda.com/howto/565/http-post-server-request

Comment: please update your html with **controller**

Comment: **<button ng-click='Booking1()'>Make Booking</button>** should be in **MapCtrl** scope

Comment: for your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464306/angularjs-ng-click-to-go-to-another-page-with-ionic-framework will help you

Comment: it working...thnks for the help

Comment: var contentString = "<button ng-click='gotoBooking()'>Book</button>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: compiled[0]
    });

Comment: one more help I wanted to add splash screen to my app...