# AngularJs ui-router $location or $state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

How can I transform this:

```
$location.path('/app/home/' + id).search({x:y});
```

to this:

```
$state.go('/app/home/' + id).search({x:y});
```

I tried, but I actually can't get enough information how to achieve that...

Comment: Use `$state.go('stateName',{id: 4})`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nice documentation *(while deprecated, still really clear)*:

#### [$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Let's say that the `state` definitions are looking like this:

```
.state('app', { // parent app
  url: '/app',
  ...
})
.state('app.home', {
  url: '/home/:x',         // the param named x
  ...
```

Then you will do

```
$state.go('app.home', {x:y});
```

This Q&A could help as well:

- [Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/)

Comment: Great to see that! Enjoy awesome `UI-Router` ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler i need to reload the page after redirecting to page. how to do it in ui-router. i have already tried $state.go('dashboard.places.list', {}, { reload: true}); it is redirecting to the particular view , but not reloads