# How to convert this line from using ng-router to ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I need to convert this line
`$location.url('/im?p=' + peer);`

to using $state, I can't seem to properly get it working. I have followed these stack overflow questions but I can't seem to get it right
[AngularJs ui-router $location or $state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138140/angularjs-ui-router-location-or-state)
[Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from)

my app.js has this state currently as this

```
$stateProvider

.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/home/index.html'
})

.state('home.matches', {
  url: '/matches/:p',
  templateUrl: 'templates/home/matches.html',
  controller: 'AppIMController'
})
```

})

app.js used to be

```
$routeProvider.when('/im', {templateUrl: templateUrl('im'), controller: 'AppIMController', reloadOnSearch: false});
```

Comment: what's the the name of the html template used with you /im route?

Comment: It's im.html but i renamed it to matches.html in using $state so they are the same but different name if I understand your question correctly

Comment: You are using query string ``p=' + peer``. So your state would be 


.state('home.matches', {
  url: '/matches?p',
  templateUrl: 'templates/home/matches.html',
  controller: 'AppIMController'
})

Comment: what about the peer variable? I use it to denote a user for example. I don't see it being used in that solution. It's the peer variable in $location.url('/im?p=' + peer);

Comment: I tried this line `$state.go('home.matches', { url: '/matches?p'+peer, templateUrl: 'templates/home/matches.html', controller: 'AppIMController' });
         ` and it still won't work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you. You don't need "peer" url property.

```
state('home.matches', {
      url: '/new?p',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home/matches.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
         $scope.peer = $stateParams.p;
      }
    })
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the peer variable instead of setting the p from the query string.