# Acess parameters of parent state from child state in stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to get the parameters from parent state.

My states look like this.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home/:param1',
            template: '<div>home<ui-view /></div>',
            data: {
            parentdata: 'parentdata'
                }
          })
        .state('home.child', {
            url: '/child/:param2',
            template: '<div>index</div>',
            data: {
            childdata: 'childdata'
                }
          })
})
```

I want to access the data value of parent state from child state.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {    
     var tosateParam = toState.data.mycustomparam;     
     //If this is the child state, how can I access the parent state param     
      //may be like this toState.parent.data.parentParam


   });
```

If my current state name is `"ABC.childstate"`, how can I access the parameters from `ABC` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case we need to access parent `data {}`, we have to... **profit** from `UI-Router`. See:

#### [What Do Child States Inherit From Parent States?](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states)

*small cite:*

> Child states **DO** inherit the following from parent states:

- Resolved dependencies via resolve
- Custom **`data {}`** properties

> ***Nothing*** else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).

Having this clear doc message, we can have states like these *(see [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OrGxQl1EFkoKBnJ1aUm?p=preview))*:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home/:param1',
        data: { parentdata: 'parentdata', },
        ...
      })
    .state('home.child', {
        url: '/child/:param2',
        data: {  childdata: 'childdata', },
        ...
      })
```

And links like these:

```
<a href="#/home/justAParent">
<a href="#/home/first1/child/second1">
<a href="#/home/first2/child/second2">
```

Will *as documentation says* result *(on a state change captured like this)*

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
   function(event, toState  , toParams, fromState, fromParams) 
    {
      console.log(toState.data)
    });
```

Into:

```
// href #/home/justAParent will show
Object {parentdata: "parentdata"}
// both #/home/first1/child/second1
//  and #/home/first2/child/second2 will show
Object {parentdata: "parentdata", childdata: "childdata"}
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OrGxQl1EFkoKBnJ1aUm?p=preview)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy awesome `UI-Router`

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSdWZoLdzxl9QvxNtAk4?p=preview). Let's have these states

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home/:param1',
        template: '<div>home<ui-view /></div>',
      })
    .state('home.child', {
        url: '/child/:param2',
        template: '<div>index</div>',
      })
```

And these links:

```
<a href="#/home/first1/child/second1">
<a href="#/home/first2/child/second2">
```

Then this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
   function(event, toState  , toParams
                   , fromState, fromParams) 
    {
      console.log(toParams)
    });
```

Will give us this:

```
Object {param1: "first1", param2: "second1"}
Object {param1: "first2", param2: "second2"}
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSdWZoLdzxl9QvxNtAk4?p=preview). Maybe also this could help a bit [Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies for my unclear question. I want to access some values from parent state. I have edited the question. Can you help me.

Comment: I've added another answer, targeting the `data {}`, while keeping this related to original `$stateParams`...