# controller in angularjs run two times

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I write an education page that has three step mainpage->allbookPage->eachbookpage->unitPage
i use rout below for switch between them but when i directly go to eachbookpage and click on a unit and go to unitpage , unit controller run two time . how can I prevent to run two time?

```
.state('education', {
        abstract:true ,
        url: "/education",
        template: '<ui-view/>',

        data: {
            breadcrumbProxy: 'education.main'
        }
    })

     .state('education.main', {

        url: "",
        templateUrl: "views/tut/education.html",
        controller:"educationCtrl",
         data: {
            displayName: 'آموزش بورس'
        },

        resolve:{
                titleOfPage: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                        return $stateParams.titleOfPage = 'آموزش بورس';
                        }]
                }

      })

      .state('education.books', {
        abstract:true,
        url: "/books",  
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
            breadcrumbProxy: 'education.books.titles'
        }
      })
       .state('education.books.titles',{
        url:"",
        templateUrl: "views/tut/books.html",
        controller:"booksCtrl",
        data: {
            displayName: 'لیست کتاب ها'
        },
        resolve:{
                titleOfPage: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                        return $stateParams.titleOfPage = 'لیست بخش ها';
                        }],
            }
      })

        .state('education.books.content',{
            abstract:true,
                url: "/:bookContentId", 
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                data: {
                    breadcrumbProxy: 'education.books.content.show'
            }

        })

         .state('education.books.content.show',{
                url:"",
                templateUrl: "views/tut/eachBook.html",
                controller:"showUnits",
                data: {
                    displayName: 'لیست بخش ها'
                },
                resolve:{
                        titleOfPage: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                                return $stateParams.titleOfPage = 'لیست بخش ها';
                                }],
                        bookContentId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,bookContentId){
                        return $stateParams.bookContentId;
                                }]
                    }
        })

          .state('education.books.content.unit',{
                url:"^/education/books/:book/:unit",
                templateUrl: "views/tut/units.html",
                 controller:"unitDetail",

                data:{
                        displayName:'{{unitName}}',
                    },
                  resolve:{
                            unit: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,unit){
                            return $stateParams.unit;
                                    }],
                            unitName: function($stateParams, newsService) {
                                 var st = $stateParams ;
                             return newsService.getUnitName($stateParams.unit).then(function(name){ 
                                    st.titleOfPage = name;                              
                                    return st.titleOfPage;
                                })
                            },
                            titleOfPage: function($stateParams, newsService) {
                                return $stateParams;
                            }
                    }

        })


          .state('education.books.content.unitrel',{
                url:"/:unit",
                templateUrl: "views/tut/units.html",
                 controller:"unitDetail",

                data:{
                        displayName:'{{unitName}}',
                    },
                  resolve:{
                            unit: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,unit){
                            return $stateParams.unit;
                                    }],
                            unitName: function($stateParams, newsService) {
                                 var st = $stateParams ;
                             return newsService.getUnitName($stateParams.unit).then(function(name){ 
                                    st.titleOfPage = name;                              
                                    return st.titleOfPage;
                                })
                            },
                            titleOfPage: function($stateParams, newsService) {
                                return $stateParams;
                            }
                    }

        })
```

Comment: can you show your html?, I think you have bind ng-controller="yourController" into html.

Comment: @Shohel i didnt use ng-controller in view , all of the controllers call in js

Comment: Are you using the controller in both the parent and child states?

Comment: @AliGajani no . according to cod that i paste it in question ,parent controller is showUnits controller .

Comment: where have you called state, write that syntax.

Comment: @Shohel education.books.content.unitrel({unit:units.id})

Comment: you can add "/" at the end of router url calling.

Comment: I guess that the problem is your url, check both unit and unitrel urls, you have some states without url, some with, try to have some convention on how you are doing things.

Comment: try like this set url:"/unitrel/:unit"
calling <a ui-sref="education.books.content.unitrel({ unit: units.id })">

Comment: Here is the link you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from