# UI Router: passing Parameters into ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) manages states for AngularJS applications and supports nested views as well as multiple named views for the same state.
Multiple named views are used like this:

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
  <div ui-view="viewB"></div>
</body>
```

You can also pass URL-parameters into states when navigating between states via `ui-sref` (Check this question: [Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from)).

**Q:** Is it possible to pass parameters to a named view using `ui-view` which then is propagated to the according state?

**Q:** How do i pass parameters if i switch between states by using `$state.go(newState)`?

**A:**
`$state.go(newState, { Param: 123 });`

Comment: you can probably use $state.go(newState, { Param: 123 })

Comment: ok, that works - i hoped i could modify the newState string, since i am relying on a 3rd Party lib which only takes a state as parameter :/

Comment: Where is the connection to my question, Michael Hobbs? Your link explains services and has nothing to do with routing.

Answer (score 0):

The `$state.go(newState, { Param: 123 })` suggested in the comments is definitely valid.

I tried using another method and it worked as well.In the main `app.js` file where I have defined my states, I defined a variable `var myData={};` outside the module definition(but in the JS file) . Think of this as a global data variable of sorts.

In the controller for `viewA` you can set a variable by setting

`myData.somevalue=$scope.valueFromViewA;`

You can access this value in `viewB` by something like

`$scope.valueInB=myData.somevalue`

As I said, this is one way of doing it, services is another and the methods in the comment are valid too.

Comment: Well you created an object which is available in all scopes. You can also use a service to share this between different controllers and have a testable angular-component :) My intention was to use multiple named views and initialize them with the same state (just different input parameters).