# How to get parameter from path?

Tags: angularjs

I work on my AngularJS project I use ui-route syntax.

My path when application starts is:

```
../../factories#/facilities/data/
```

Or sometimes it has some parameter:

```
 ../../factories#/facilities/data/55
```

How can I check if path contains parameter if it is, how can I get it from the path?

Comment: are you using ng route or ui route

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I use ui-route

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from

Comment: @Michael, then use `$stateParams`

Comment: @Satpal can you show example?I get undefined value.

Comment: use $stateParams and print it in to console.log..you will get some values there..